# Angular - ng-bind-html not working due to ngSanitize error

Tags: angularjs

[Please see relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/443/)

Within this file even though I included angular.sanitize.js I am not able to bind the html elements.

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="snippet in myHTML" ng-bind-html="snippet"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ['ngSanitize'])

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myHTML = [];  

  $scope.myHTML.push('<li>Test1</li>');  
  $scope.myHTML.push('<li>Test2</li>');  

});
```

Nothing is being displayed when running the jsFiddle. When debugging I am getting an injector error.

Please let me know if you need any more relevant information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `ngSanitize` is loaded *after* Angular. Updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/444/